# Tango to Eagle Schematic import

Tags: eaglecad, cad

Does anyone know a way to get Tango schematics into Eagle? Even if it is a hard way (other than entering from scratch)... Of course, an easy way would be nice.

Cheers,

Marcus

Answer (score 1):

Is Tango open source? Is their format documented? If so, Eagle has a scripting language, depending on how many schematics you have, it might be worth spending the time learning the scripting language and writing a tool to import it.

You should also ask on the Eagle newsgroups, it's on usenet which is kind of obscure, but you can use Mozilla Thunderbird to read/post to them.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to import the netlist into Eagle, then get everything sorted back out into a usable schematic.